# Insert empty pages until certain page number

Tags: page-breaking, loops

I have sections which have to start exactly at the predefined page numbers and the potentially unfilled pages between these sections should be filled with empty pages. Is there a for-loop available that would insert `\newpage` until the right page where the new section starts is reached?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without any package, you can do with `\loop`; the trick is to add something invisible to the empty pages, for instance `\null` (more efficient than `\mbox{}`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filluptopage}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \loop\ifnum\value{page}<#1\relax
    \null\clearpage
  \repeat
}

\begin{document}
Page 1 has text.

\filluptopage{5}

This will be at page 5.
\end{document}
```